# Compare code between two stored procedures in two different databases in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

There are two stored procedures which has same name and same logic. But in different databases. Only some of the content names are different (example - Synonym Name, Table Name, schema). Other code is the same.

Is there any way to compare code between above two stored procedures?

Comment: If you have rights to script them and see their code, just use some external tool like `Beyond Compare` or compare plugin for `NotePad++` and see the differences.

Comment: http://text-compare.com/ copy paste both codes here, if you are lazy like me to download a tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many type of comparisons (folder, text, etc.) you can use  [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) (they offers 30 days trial, but after it, you can simple reinstall it).

[image]

If you want something free, you can use a compare plugin for `NotePad++` but is not so fancy as the first tool:

[image]

The `Plugin Manager` can be opened from `Plugins -> Plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager`.

Answer (score 7):

Personally i prefer to use a SSDT Project (SQL Server Data Tools)

It allows you to store the entire database schema in a Visual Studio project and in git/svn.

It is capable of comparing two databases (in full) or a database with the SSDT project schema.  It will show you the differences and allow you to publish those differences.

Configurable and powerful.

I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the file comparison tool **'Araxis Merge'** to compare files in my project.

Please check the link to download the tool - http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en

You can download the 30 days free trial version also.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the source code for stored procedures can readily be retrieved from the database, they should really reside in a VCS for any database that is (or will be) productionised.

Historically, this has been something of a manual process but later versions of Visual Studio include the SQL Server Database Project type which makes development and deployment much easier.

The question then becomes the far easier one of how to compare files within the VCS which is typically trivial as this sort of thing is generally provided out of the box.

Comment: Version Control systems compare stored procedure between versions. But my problem is between two different SP's. Not the same SP's Different version.

Comment: You're not limited to comparing versions. As long as they're in the same repository, you can compare pretty much anything.

Comment: Can we compare two different files with VCS ?

Comment: Yep - and we do so regularly. We have different branches for dev and live and often run compares for something like WeeklySalesReportv9.sql in dev against WeeklySalesReportv8.sql in live.

Answer (score 2):

[Aquastudio](http://www.aquafold.com/aquadatastudio.html) does it pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of [MssqlMerge](https://ksdbmerge.tools/mssqlmerge) (I am the author) to compare code of stored procedures, functions and views. To compare two SPs in the same DB, same or different SPs between different DBs, located on the same or different servers (even across different networks - you can connect to vpn #1 and read db #1 and then disconnect vpn #1 and connect vpn #2 and read db #2 to compare with db #1).